# LinqToTwitter Error - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, webforms, ssl-certificate

I've found several different questions about this error, but none of them seem to outline my scenario.

I am creating a website that pulls in tweets from our company's Twitter account, and displaying them on a social wall.  I am using C# asp.NET webforms.  The C# code uses a Linqtotwitter library to handle the authentication and the "tweet pulling."  It grabs the tweets and dumps them onto an aspx file as a big long string of json.  We then have a jquery script that reads through the json and displays the tweets on the page nice and pretty like.

The code currently works perfect on my dev box.  But when I push the code up to production I get this .NET error:

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

I'll provide my code in a bit here, but first let me give you a little background.  I have no idea if this information would be relevant or not, but who knows.  This website is actually part of a larger project to fit several tiny one page microsites that we get from marketing onto one server to reduce the overhead they cause.  These microsites can all have a different host name, but they point to the same IP address.  An httpmodule lives on that server, and intercepts all requests coming in, and redirects them to an appropriate sub folder depending on the host name.

From the research that I've done, it seems that SSL is tied into this error quite a bit.  I'm still pretty new to the IT world, and I'm learning more about SSL as this troubleshooting goes on.  The server these microsites live on does have a few SSL certificates on it, and one of the microsites uses SSL, but not the website I'm currently working on.  But since they both share the same IP address in that sense they kind of ARE the same website.

This is the C# LinqtoTwitter code:

```
    private SingleUserAuthorizer auth;
    private TwitterContext twitterCtx;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
        {
            Credentials = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentials
            {
                ConsumerKey =
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerKey"],
                ConsumerSecret =
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterConsumerSecret"],
                TwitterAccessToken =
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessToken"],
                TwitterAccessTokenSecret =
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterAccessTokenSecret"]
            }
        };

        if (auth.IsAuthorized)
        {
            twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
            var tweetResponse =
           (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
            where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                  tweet.ScreenName == "OurProfile" &&
                  tweet.IncludeRetweets == true
            select tweet)
           .ToList();

            Results.Text = twitterCtx.RawResult;
        }

    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        if (twitterCtx != null)
        {
            twitterCtx.Dispose();
            twitterCtx = null;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be the problem here?  Like I said, I'm still pretty new, and I'm at a loss here even how to troubleshoot this issue beyond Google. Could it be something where our server can't verify that Twitter's SSL certificate is from a trusted source?  Let me know if I can provide any more information or any more code.  Thanks for your time and for reading through my post!